# Getting Second-to-Last Element in List

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am able to get the second-to-last element of a list with the following:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> print(lst[len(lst)-2])
e
```

Is there a better way than using `print(lst[len(lst)-2])` to achieve this same result?

Comment: Try `lst[-2]`...

Comment: And yes, it is a duplicate; note how the top/accepted answer gives an example for the second to last element as well.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

There is: negative indices:

```
lst[-2]
```

Comment: Even with the knowledge of `-1` I didn't think to subtract more... thank you! I will accept when the time limit is over.